# What is the functional group of zerumbone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am currently doing research on antioxidant activity of essential oil from Zingiber zerumbet. The essential oil contain zerumbone. The problem is I am confuse about the functional group of zerumbone is it ketone or aldehyde or what. I want to do thin layer chromatography test to identify the purity of the essential oil but I don't know how to identify it.

Answer (score 5):

Zerumbone, a constituent of the rhizomes of wild ginger (*Zingiber zerumbet*), is (2​*E*​,6​*E*​,10​*E*​)-​2,6,9,9-​​tetramethylcycloundeca-​2,6,10-trienone; i.e. it is a ketone.

[image: Zerumbone]